# 3 Way Node Connection UDP Python Programming Error

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

There 3 python code files, A, B and C.

A sends a message to B and B receives it and forwards it to C, receives it and prints it out. All 3 of them use UDP protocol. I know I only have to change a few lines, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

B does not bind to A, and A sends the message to C directly. I get host errors because I have issues connecting them together.

Note, **it is only part B that needs to be changed, but I included part A and C for reference.**

Part A:

```
import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <ip> <listen port>")
    sys.exit(-1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    print("Input text:")
    text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    s.sendto(text,(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2])))
    if text == "bye":
        break
```

Part B:

```
import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <listen port>")
    sys.exit(-1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])))

print("Waiting..")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.sendto(data,(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2])))
    if data == "bye":
        break
```

Part C:

```
import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <listen port>")
    sys.exit(-1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])))
print("Waiting..")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    data = data.decode("utf-8").replace("\0","")
    print data
    if data == "bye":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, had to include the IP address for the B code, binding it to A, as seen in the code below.

```
import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <liseten port>")
    sys.exit(-1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])))
print("Waiting..")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.sendto(data,("127.0.0.1",int(sys.argv[2])))
    if data.decode("utf-8") == "bye":
        break
```